# Why is Hibernate returning some null items in a OneToMany collection?

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpql

Fetching an entity and its collection from the database includes null objects. This is in contrast to a postgresql query, which returns no null objects.

I tried a JPQL query `select pa from PreAlignment pa left join fetch pa.preAlignmentSources order by pa.id asc` into a processor where it finds null collection items. Meanwhile, if I run the same query in the console `select * from pre_alignment_sources where pre_alignment_id = 4151;` it simply returns two good rows without any null objects.

Here's what it looks like in the debug window when I run the Spring Batch Job and stop on line 36 in the processor.

[image]

Here's the result of running `select * from pre_alignment_sources where pre_alignment_id = 4151;` in the console. The order column is cut off, but it says 0 and 1 respectively.

[image]

## Files

### PreAlignment Entity

```
package nathanlively.subalignercss.adapter.out.persistence;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import nathanlively.subalignercss.Models.BaseEntity;
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;

import java.io.Serial;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table(name = "pre_alignments")
public class PreAlignment extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3564048730879366680L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Builder.Default()
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "preAlignment", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @ToString.Exclude
    @OrderColumn
    private List<PreAlignmentSource> preAlignmentSources = new LinkedList<>();

    @Builder.Default
    @Column(name = "is_from_manufacturer")
    private Boolean isFromManufacturer = false;

    @Builder.Default
    @Column(name = "is_from_user")
    private Boolean isFromUser = false;

    @Builder.Default
    @Column(name = "is_public", nullable = false)
    private Boolean isPublic = false;

    @Column(name = "score")
    private float score;

    @Column(name = "notes")
    private String notes;

    public void addPreAlignmentSource(PreAlignmentSource preAlignmentSource) {
        preAlignmentSources.add(preAlignmentSource);
        preAlignmentSource.setPreAlignment(this);
    }

    public void removePreAlignmentSource(PreAlignmentSource preAlignmentSource) {
        preAlignmentSources.remove(preAlignmentSource);
        if(preAlignmentSource != null) {
            preAlignmentSource.setPreAlignment(null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || Hibernate.getClass(this) != Hibernate.getClass(o)) return false;
        PreAlignment that = (PreAlignment) o;
        return getId() != null && Objects.equals(getId(), that.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }
}
```

### PreAlignmentSource Entity

```
package nathanlively.subalignercss.adapter.out.persistence;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import nathanlively.subalignercss.Models.BaseEntity;
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;

import java.io.Serial;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table(name = "pre_alignment_sources")
public class PreAlignmentSource extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5343480867438042527L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "pre_alignment_id")
    private PreAlignment preAlignment;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "speaker_id", nullable = false)
    private Speaker speaker;

    @Builder.Default
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean polarity = false;  // false = 0 = normal; true = 1 = inverted;

    @Builder.Default
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Float delay = 0F;

    @Builder.Default
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Float gain = 0F;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || Hibernate.getClass(this) != Hibernate.getClass(o)) return false;
        PreAlignmentSource that = (PreAlignmentSource) o;
        return getId() != null && Objects.equals(getId(), that.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }
}
```

### removeNullSourcePreAlignments Step inside of cleanDatabaseJob inside of BatchConfiguration

```
@Bean
    public Step removeNullSourcePreAlignments(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
                                              JpaItemWriter<PreAlignment> preAlignmentWriter, NullSourceItemProcessor nullSourceItemProcessor) {
        return new StepBuilder("removeNullSourcePreAlignments", jobRepository)
                .<PreAlignment, PreAlignment>chunk(100, transactionManager)
                .reader(preAlignmentJpaItemReader())
                .processor(nullSourceItemProcessor)
                .writer(preAlignmentWriter)
                .build();
    }

@Bean
    public JpaCursorItemReader<PreAlignment> preAlignmentJpaItemReader() {
        return new JpaCursorItemReaderBuilder<PreAlignment>()
                .name("preAlignmentJpaItemReader")
                .entityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory)
                .queryString("select pa from PreAlignment pa left join fetch pa.preAlignmentSources order by pa.id asc")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NullSourceItemProcessor nullSourceItemProcessor() {
        return new NullSourceItemProcessor();
    }

 @Bean
    public JpaItemWriter<PreAlignment> preAlignmentWriter() {
        return new JpaItemWriterBuilder<PreAlignment>()
                .entityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory)
                .build();
    }
```

### NullSourceItemProcessor

```
package nathanlively.subalignercss.BatchProcessing.CleanDatabase;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import nathanlively.subalignercss.adapter.out.persistence.PreAlignment;
import nathanlively.subalignercss.adapter.out.persistence.PreAlignmentSource;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;


@Log4j2
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class NullSourceItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<PreAlignment, PreAlignment> {
    private static int counter = 0;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public PreAlignment process(@NotNull PreAlignment preAlignment) throws Exception {
        counter++;
        if (counter % 100 == 0) {
            log.info("Searching for null sources. Processing hundredth PreAlignment with id: " + preAlignment.getId());
        }

        List<PreAlignmentSource> sourcesToRemove = preAlignment.getPreAlignmentSources().stream()
                .filter(Objects::isNull)
                .toList();

        if (!sourcesToRemove.isEmpty()) {
            log.info("Found null source on preAlignment " + preAlignment.getId() + ". Attempting to remove.");
            for (PreAlignmentSource source : sourcesToRemove) {
                preAlignment.removePreAlignmentSource(source);
            }
            return preAlignment;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: One thing I discovered today: If a collection of 3 items is returned and two of them have the same order column value, then one of them will be null. For example, I found a preAlignment with three preAlignment sources who order values were 0, 0, and 2. It should be 0, 1, 2. Instead of showing all of them, the collection only showed the first and last. The middle, with the duplicate order value, was shown as null.

Answer (score 2):

This is by design. Left Join is supposed to return null values if no matching is found.

This is JPA Query:

```
select pa from PreAlignment pa left join fetch pa.preAlignmentSources order by pa.id asc
```

It is translated to native SQL like this:

```
select pa.id, pas.pre_alignment_id from pre_alignments pa left join pre_alignment_sources pas on pa.id = pas.pre_alignment_id order by pa.id asc
```

If pa.id doesn't have correspondent column with pas.pre_alignment_id, then pa.id is still returned, but pas.pre_alignment_id will be null.

For example, if pre_alignments has the following values:

```
id
1
2
```

and pre_alignment_sources has the following values:

```
id pre_alignment_id
1      1
2      1
```

Then the result of the query will be:

```
pa.id     pas.pre_alignment_id pas.id
1          1                    1
1          1                    2
2          null                 null
```

This is why you have null elements in the result.
If we convert this example to your hibernate result, then you will have 2 pre_alignement_sources elements for pre_alignement with id = 1 and 1 NULL pre_alignment_sources element for pre_alignment with id = 2

- pa.id = 1 (pas.id = 1, pas.id = 2)
- pa.id = 2 (pas.id = NULL)

P.S. If you need to filter out NULL values, then the following query should work:

```
select pa from PreAlignment pa left join fetch pa.preAlignmentSources WHERE pa.preAlignmentSources IS NOT NULL order by pa.id asc
```

In this case, the result should not contain pre_allignments, which don't have any pre_alignment_sources:

```
pa.id     pas.pre_alignment_id pas.id
1          1                    1
1          1                    2
```

Please, note that in this case, pa.id = 2 will not be returned and you will not have a collection witn NULL values.

Comment: Hi Mykhailo, thanks so much for your answer. I can't say that I completely understand it, yet. My intention with this JPA query is simply to do an eager fetch of pre_alignments and its pre_alignment_sources so that each collection can be checked for null items. Is the JPA query incorrect?

Comment: If you need to filter out null values, then the following query should work:
select pa from PreAlignment pa left join fetch pa.preAlignmentSources WHERE pa.preAlignmentSources IS NOT NULL order by pa.id asc

Comment: Thanks Mykhailo. I want to filter in null values so that they can be identified and removed.